# Entity State Always Changed to Modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have been using Entity Framework for a few years now. My project is Database First. I recently upgraded to EF 6 from EF 4. I have code generating templates that create partial classes with the following code for scalar properties:

```
    Private Nullable<double> _ScalarProp;
    public virtual Nullable<double> ScalarProp
    { 
        get
        {
            return _ScalarProp;
        } 
        set
        {
            if(_ScalarProp != value)
            {
                if(IsNotifyEnabled)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanging("ScalarProp");
                    OnScalarPropChanging();
                }
                _ScalarProp = value;
                if(IsNotifyEnabled)
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged("ScalarProp");
                    OnScalarPropChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    partial void OnScalarPropChanging();
    partial void OnScalarPropChanged();
```

My problem is that when assigning a value to a property that is identical to its current value the above code bypasses the assignment statement HOWEVER the state of the entity goes from Unchanged to Modified. What is happening? Is the Change Tracker operating completely independently of the templated entities? How can I resolve this so the Entity remains Unchanged when the assigned value is identical to the current value?

Comment: Try making the property non virtual. I think EF is generating overrides that set the stage to modified on property changed rather than subscribing to your events.

Comment: Hmmm. When I created my T4 templates (EF 4) properties had to be virtual (something about the proxy entity objects needing to override to add their magic). Has that changed in EF 6?

Comment: No, you can have non virtual properties, and they get serialized but I bet they would eliminate the behavior that you're seeing. It would mean you will need to manually mark entities as modified. Probably not something you want to have to do in your code, but just as a test it might be informative.

Comment: So what you are saying is that by making them `virtual`, I am allowing the `ChangeTracker` to take over marking the `EntityState`. If I remove `virtual` then I will have to mark the entity as Modified within the property setter? Will the `ChangeTracker` still do the fixup on my associations?

Comment: If the property is not virtual, `ChangeTracker` will not be aware of any changes made to the property because EF won't be able to override the property and inject its tracking code. To be clear, I'm not suggesting you do this as a fix, only as a test to better understand what the behavior is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the issue is that the `ChangeTracker` does not attempt to distinguish if the new value differs from the existing value in its overrides of my property setters. Instead it simply marks a property as modified whenever the setter is called. That seems odd to me as I would think it would try to minimize the traffic back to the database by weeding out the non-changes. I would be interested to know if this is the behavior that others are seeing or if it is simply quirk of my particular implementation of EF (translation: I screwed something up). As a workaround I have added the following method to the base class for my entities:

```
public abstract class EntityBase: INotifyPropertyChanged, INotifyPropertyChanging
{
  ...

  public bool WasUpdated()
  {
    var entry = MyEntities.Context.Entry(this);
    if (entry.State != EntityState.Modified)
      return false;
    bool changed = false;
    foreach (var propName in entry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
    {
      changed = changed || (entry.CurrentValues[propName] != entry.OriginalValues[propName]  && !entry.CurrentValues[propName].Equals(entry.OriginalValues[propName]));
      if (changed)
        break;
    }
    return changed;
  }
}
```

I'll use this until someone is able to help me figure out whether this is the intended behavior of `ChangeTracker` or I have just screwed up my implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Is the value being set the result of a calculation? Equality comparison with doubles can have unexpected behavior if those values are the results of calculations. You may want to implement a comparison with tolerance

```
if (Math.Abs(_ScalarProp.Value - value.Value) > 0.000001)
{  // etc.
```

(You will need to manually check for null values of your nullable types before using this.)

Comment: Double was just an example. Happens if it is another type like string or DateTime.

Comment: Datetime can actually have a similar problem, because it can store things down to microseconds but these won't because survive some serialization round trips. Does the issue happen with int?

Comment: I really don't think that is the issue. Tracing through the code, it does not make it past the `if( _ScalarProp != value)`.

Comment: Yes, because EF is marking the entity as modified in its override without checking to see if the new value is different

Answer (score 0):

Dont have the answer. But I have a tool to find when and why.
Add to your context class. You can call it from the immediate window anytime.

```
myContext.FullDump();

public void FullDump(bool ignoreUnchanged = false)
    {

        Debug.WriteLine("=====Begin of Context Dump=======");
        var dbsetList = this.ChangeTracker.Entries();
        foreach (var dbEntityEntry in dbsetList)
        {
            if (ignoreUnchanged && dbEntityEntry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
            {
                continue;
            }
            Debug.WriteLine(dbEntityEntry.Entity.GetType().Name + " => " + dbEntityEntry.State);
            switch (dbEntityEntry.State)
            {
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Detached:
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Unchanged:
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Added:
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified:
                    WriteCurrentValues(dbEntityEntry);
                    break;
                case System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted:
                    WriteOriginalValues(dbEntityEntry);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("==========End of Entity======");
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("==========End of Context======");
    }

    private static void WriteCurrentValues(DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry)
    {
        foreach (var cv in dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(cv + "=" + dbEntityEntry.CurrentValues[cv]);
        }
    }
    private static void WriteOriginalValues(DbEntityEntry dbEntityEntry)
    {
        foreach (var cv in dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(cv + "=" + dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues[cv]);
        }
    }
}
```